# User Input not working on Text Field added programmatically in Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I am trying to add a user-editable text field. I was able to get the text field to appear for each different cell of the table, but I wasn't able to get users to input. It doesn't show the keyboard. I have user interaction enabled. This is my code. Please ignore the commented out parts.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "transportCell", for: indexPath)

  //self.tableView.rowHeight = 100



    //var a = Array(words[indexPath.row])

    //a.shuffle()

    //var shuffledWord = String(a)


    //shuffledWord = shuffledWord.lowercased()

    let sampleTextField =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
    sampleTextField.placeholder = "Enter text here"
    sampleTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    sampleTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
    sampleTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
    sampleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.alphabet
    sampleTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    sampleTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing;
    sampleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
    sampleTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate


   // cell.textLabel?.text = shuffledWord

   // var imageName = UIImage(named: words[indexPath.row])
    //cell.imageView?.image = imageName

    return cell
}
```

If possible could you also tell me how to store the user's input as a variable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You never add the text field to the cell. You really should have a custom cell class that sets up the text field for itself. That code does not belong in `cellForRowAt`.

Answer (score 3):

As @rmaddy said that first, you have to add that text field to your cell for that ...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {......

  sampleTextField.text = arrTextFieldVal[indexPath.item]//this array for stroing the user input values..
  sampleTextField.tag = indexPath.item // u will access the text field with this value 
  cell.addSubview(sampleTextField)........}
```

and second, you can store user values by manage an array of string like ...

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrTextFieldVal.count }
```

and take values from text field delegate like this...

```
 func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    arrTextFieldVal[textField.tag] = textField.text!
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Comment: Cells get reused. You will end up adding more and more text fields to each cell with code like this.

Comment: Benjamin Okeefe student use a custom cell with textfield otherwise problem will be there as @rmaddy mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48800382/2282149) see if it helps you.

- Also, please check that you are not resigning keyboard on textFieldShouldBeginEditing, shouldChangeCharactersIn or textFieldShouldBeginEditing delegates of textfield.